# Solving $f(4)$ Known : $f(x).g'(x) + g'(x).f'(x) = 4x^3 - 8x$, $g(0)f(0)=0$ and $g'(x) - f'(x) = 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Known : $f(x).g'(x) + g'(x).f'(x) = 4x^3 - 8x$, $g(0)f(0)=0$ and $g'(x) - f'(x) = 4$

Find f(4). Options : 24,20,16,12,8

Solving the 3 equations given, i get 
$(4+f'(x))(f(x) + f'(x)) = 4x^3-8x$
$f'(x)=-4$
$f(4) = -16$
Is there no answer? Some hints anyone?
EDIT :
[image]

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Please check whether you have a typo in the problem.  If the 1st equation is (instead) $f(x)\times g^{\prime}(x) + g(x)\times f^{\prime}(x) = 4x^3 + 8x$, then I think I can solve it.

Comment: Ok i checked it is fx.g'x + g'x.f'x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my previous comment: this *answer* **assumes** that the original problem has the corresponding typo.

Let $h(x) = f(x)\times g(x).$ Then, $h(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 + C.$

Since $h(0) = 0, C= 0.$

It is desired to find two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so that :

(1) $f(x) \times g(x) = x^4 - 4x^2$ and

(2) $g(x) - f(x) = 4x.$

The solution seems to be $g(x) = x^2 + 2x, \;f(x) = x^2 - 2x.$

Comment: Ok. Maybw its typo...